# MVVM WPF: trying to use @Parameter in my stored procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a WPF business application, connected to SQL Server and I'm trying to adhere to the MVVM design pattern.

I am using the Stylet framework, but am open to answers using any other or no frameworks, as long as I am able to get it working.

Stylet automatically couples the ViewModel with the View.

What I am trying to achieve: I have created a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLicense]
    @Foretaksnavn nvarchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT tblLicense.ID, LøyvehaverID, KjøretøyID
    FROM tblLicense
    INNER JOIN tblLicenseHolder ON tblLicense.LøyvehaverID = tblLicenseHolder.Foretaksnummer
    WHERE tblLicense.LøyvehaverID = @Foretaksnavn
```

And I want to use it in order to fill a DataGrid (name: `dgLicense`). I am coupling two columns using the `INNER JOIN` function, and setting the parameter to be `@Foretaksnavn`.

So far - so good.

And then I have written a method, which is in the ViewModel corresponding to the View containing the DataGrid. It looks like this:

```
public void FillDataGridLicenses() 
{
    try 
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new("getLicense", sqlCon))
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDaAd = new(sqlCmd))
        using (DataSet ds = new()) 
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Foretaksnavn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = /* MISSING CODE GOES HERE */;

            sqlDaAd.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
            {
                Licenses.Add(new License {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                    LøyvehaverID = dr[1].ToString(),
                    KjøretøyID = dr[2].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

The /* MISSING CODE GOES HERE */ part is where I need help.
I have a label in the `Window` which has the data that would work as parameter-value, but I don't know how to access it.
The label gets it content like this:

First I put the `DataContext` of the `Canvas` like this (this for some reason has to be done even though Stylet couples the `View` with the `ViewModel`):

`DataContext="{Binding Path=(viewmodel:LicenseHolderViewModel.Selected)}"`

and I've bound the contents of the label like this:

`Content="{Binding Foretaksnavn}"`

"Foretaksnavn" is a property holder bound to an BindableCollection (pretty much the same as an ObservableCollection), and corresponds to the Sql server column of the same name which holds the rows I want to sort the DataGrid by.

**How can I access the value of it?**

This is the XAML markup for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid
            x:Name="dgLicense"
            Canvas.Left="315"
            Canvas.Top="501"
            Width="332"
            Height="214"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BorderBrush="#FF707070"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            FontSize="14"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Loaded="{s:Action FillDataGridLicenses}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="ID"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Løyve"               
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="122"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    Visibility="Visible" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=LøyveID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Reg.nr"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Visible" 
                    Width="92"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Registreringsnummer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Modell"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    Width="*"
                    Visibility="Visible" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Kjøretøymodell, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Operasjonsdato"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Operasjonsdato, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`Licenses` is an instantiation of a `BindableCollection` (Stylets variant of `ObservableCollection`), which get its data from a holder class; License.cs, which looks like this:

```
using Stylet;

namespace Ridel.Hub 
{
    public class License : PropertyChangedBase 
    {
        private int _id;
        public int ID 
        {
            get { return this._id; }
            set { SetAndNotify(ref this._id, value); }
        }

        private string _løyvehaverID;
        public string LøyvehaverID 
        {
            get { return this._løyvehaverID; }
            set { SetAndNotify(ref this._løyvehaverID, value); }
        }

        private string _kjøretøyID;
        public string KjøretøyID 
        {
            get { return this._kjøretøyID; }
            set { SetAndNotify(ref this._kjøretøyID, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Very grateful if anyone can provide any sort of tips or assistance!

Comment: Which line exactly is throwing the exception? Side note: you don't need `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`, you can just loop a reader `using(var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()) while (reader.Read()) .....`

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Foretaksnavn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LblHeaderText.ToString();` is causing the exception.
Thank you for the side note, I will definitively look into that!

Comment: I would imagine `LblHeaderText` is null for whatever reason, or perhaps you really want `LblHeaderText.Text`

Comment: I've done an embarrassing mistake, and will update my question...

Comment: @Charlieface, I've now updated my question. Turns out I done goofed, and had used an entirely different method to bind the content of my label. Thanks a bunch!